# How could I cache db query when I use Parallel in a action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

In my action, I try to use [Parallel](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) to produce thread to do some calculation. It's something like this:

```
def index
  Parallel.map(User.all, in_threads: 4) do |user|
    # do some calculation
    # will query db many times
  end
end
```

After reading [SQL Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching), I think because it's in a same action, the db query should be cached. But it's not happening. When I don't use Parallel, it will cache db query.

How could I cache db query when I use Parallel?